# Google Chrome disable window animations

Tags: google-chrome, animation, window-managers

After updating to Chrome 58 I noticed a new "zoom-fade" effect when restoring a minimized window, or opening a new window (Ctrl+N). This feels very unnecessary, and - in my desktop environment - totally out of place.

Is there a way to permanently disable all window animation effects?

Comment: FYI, same question on SU: [How can I turn off animations in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1140564/how-can-i-turn-off-animations-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable the animation by adding the `--wm-window-animations-disabled` command-line flag.

For Linux/Ubuntu you can make this permanent by editing the Chrome shortcut at `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`. There are 3 `Exec=` lines where you will need to add `--wm-window-animations-disabled` immediately after the executable name.

If you find that this is no longer working, re-check your shortcuts as some Chrome updates (via a package manager) could have overwritten the shortcut(s), so you may need to re-edit them.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Slapped this in the XFCE shortcut and it worked great. I'm sure the Chrome team will disable that flag in about 9 months, but I can avoid the nauseating zoom until then, at least.

Comment: This isn't working for me.   Ubuntu 17.04 

Chrome 58.0.3029.110 
i3 desktop

Comment: This worked for me, but changing that desktop file didn't help. Probably this is because I start google chrome by clicking a shortcut icon in the menu bar. So, I had to add this flag to that shortcut icon by right-clicking it and modifying the command.

Comment: @zamicol change it where you start it from. might be another direct short cut? try from the command line first

Comment: Looks like with Chrome 60 and 61 this has been fixed. So the command-line flag is no longer necessary. I marked this as the accepted answer since it did help with Chrome 58 (and 59?).

Comment: Do you have a solution also for macOS?

Answer (score 4):

There's easy way to get rid of those animations everywhere & permanently under Linux.

Here's an example for Ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/dis_wm-window-anim
```

(on Debian its /etc/chromium.d/dis_wm-window-anim)

then

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --wm-window-animations-disabled"
```

Ctrl+x -> y -> "enter"

Comment: Oneliner for Debian, as root: `echo 'CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --wm-window-animations-disabled"' > /etc/chromium.d/dis_wm-window-anim`. Then restart Chromium. Looks so much snappier and better. Thanks Yevgen!

Comment: Any idea how to do this for macOS?

Answer (score 3):

go to developer tools and then click top right menu click More tools and then click Animation 
in top and left of Animation Tab you can see play and pause button by click on it you can stop and play animation

Comment: tried, not related to the problem described in the question

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great for a glow effect in a web-panel that was draining 90% cpu usage